# regex: lookbehind assertation

Tags: php, regex

i use **`((\d)(\d(?!\2))((?<!\3)\d(?!\3)))\1`** to match arbitrary digit that not same one row sort like:

234234, 345345, 359359 **but not match 211211, 355355** (removing the lookbehind assertation will match these)

i found the pattern got error when run with preg_match() in PHP since the length of offset must fixed, but its OK when tested in other debuger (i use kodos in this case)

**preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 23**

Are there any alternative of the pattern to match sort digit above? 245245 or other digit that fit ABCABC format pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the lookbehind, this turns it into a lookahead and seems to work for me [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bO9xQ3)

```
((\d)(\d(?!\2))(?!\3)(\d(?!\3)))\1
```

Comment: all answer here is working fine, but i chose matching each group for future safety

Answer (score 1):

if the 3 digits must be different you can use:

```
((\d)(?!.?\2)(\d)(?!\3)\d)\1
```

but if `545545` is allowed you can use:

```
((\d)(?!\2)(\d)(?!\3)\d)\1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you please explain how `.?` in `((\d)(?!.?\2)(\d)(?!\3)\d)\1` works, i didnt get it :/

Comment: @Enissay: `.?` is an optional character, then the assertion `(?!.?\2)` is equivalent to `(?!(?:\2|.\2))` and checks if the second digit is not the same and if the third digit is not the same in one shot.

Comment: `(?!.?\2) is equivalent to (?!(?:\2|.\2))` That's what I was looking for, thks <3

Answer (score 0):

Just use lookahead instead of lookbehind?

```
((\d)(?!\2)(\d)(?!\2|\3)\d)\1
```

Explained by [Regex Explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%28%5Cd%29%28%3F%21%5C2%29%28%5Cd%29%28%3F%21%5C2%7C%5C3%29%5Cd%29%5C1):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \2                       what was matched by capture \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \2                       what was matched by capture \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \3                       what was matched by capture \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1                       what was matched by capture \1
```